Streamlining "Extract/unzip here" on Windows 11
One of the most common actions I do on Windows is extracting zips from downloaded files. While simple, it bothers me it takes so many actions to achieve, even with the best recognized apps like 7-zip and NanaZip.
Windows 11 made things worse with its context menu, but luckily NanaZip fixed that.
But I'd love to still find a better solution.
99.9% of the time I'm using "Extract Here".
I'd love to find a solution that checked these boxes if possible:

"Extract here" option easily available. Not behind a Software name submenu, as it makes me wait 500ms more till the next menu opens. This MUST be doable, since NanaZip and several other apps manage to insert themselves in the top layer of Windows 11 context menu. I just don't want their name. I want the action directly there.
Alternatively, a keyboard shortcut to auto-extract here a selected file. This way we can ignore the context menu and its hardships.
Ideally, an option to "Extract here + Auto-delete zip". That would be blissful for me as it's the workflow every single time.

Current workflow:

I'm open to anything. Apps, tools, or whatever. Can't program myself, but willing to use less user friendly options if required to achieve this seemingly simple thing.

Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers.

I recommend disabling the crappy new context menus. You then have all the customization options from the golden age. 7-zip supports configuring what’s in the context menu and how it’s organized.

As @DanielB states, in 7-Zip: Tools | Options | 7-Zip tab -- uncheck Cascaded context menu.

@DanielB Thanks, yeah I'll do that. Just reinstalled 7-zip and cleaned it up. Now I'll see what I can find to clean THAT context menu, as it's much longer than the new one.

Please note that you've already been told that asking for product and service recommendations are off topic on this site. To avoid your question being closed, I strongly recommend that you modify the last sentence of your post to remove the request portion of your question and present a question that IS on topic.
